# Javascript how to write as object compared to Ruby

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I'm too frustrated with ruby on rails and getting gems to work; so I'm getting back into Javascript for little challenges.  My problem is that I feel that I have an idea of how to start writing a function for ruby and call it from elsewhere.  I would write my application like this:

```
class checkinActions
  def CheckinPrompt
    // do things
  end

  def amenityList
    // another function
  end
end
```

Currently I have a test file (`test.js`); and I'm running it by simply running:

```
node test.js
```

What is a good example of wrapping the current javascript functionality I have in this file; and having it as a function that I can call from elsewhere?

```
// Variables Section
const customerData = require('./assets/customers.json');
const corporationData = require('./assets/corporations.json');

var today = "17" // setting this to 17th since all the unix timestamps in the customers.json file are on the day of the 17th
// customerId = 0 // Just assuming that this is the primary input for now.  i.e. system asks for generating checkin message for customer X
var raw_time = new Date();
var hotel_time = new Date(raw_time).toLocaleString();
var morningNight = hotel_time.slice(-2)

for (let index = 0; index < customerData.length; ++index) {
  
  var raw_time = new Date();
  var hotel_time = new Date(raw_time).toLocaleString();
  var morningNight = hotel_time.slice(-2)
  var roomPrefix = String(customerData[index].reservation.roomNumber)[0];
  var roomPrefixBacktonum = Number(roomPrefix) - 1;
  var companyName = corporationData[roomPrefixBacktonum].company;
  var companyCity = corporationData[roomPrefixBacktonum].city;
  var corporateMessage = " and Welcome to the Fabulous "  + companyName + " in dazzling " + companyCity;

  if (day = today) {   // This section is assuming that today is the 17th
    // console.log("worked");
    if (morningNight == "AM") {
    greetingSection = "Good Morning "
      } else if (morningNight == "PM") {
        greetingSection = "Good Evening "
      } else {          // this else section is a catch-all and a place to expand more complicated time edge cases
        greetingSection = "Hello "
      };

    // Customer Name Section
    nameSection = customerData[index].firstName

    // Room Details Section
    roomDetailsMessage = " Room " + customerData[index].reservation.roomNumber + " is ready for you now.  Please enjoy yourself, text this number for any questions, concerns, or requests!"

    // Output Section
    checkinMessage = greetingSection + nameSection + "," + corporateMessage + roomDetailsMessage;
    console.log(checkinMessage);
  } else {
  console.log("No Action - not time to check in yet");
  }
};
```

Comment: If your question is how to wrap your JS code as a function so that you can call it from elsewhere...: just wrap it in a function? `function showCustomerdata() {..your code..}`

Comment: I must have been up too late, that worked fine.  The simplest things sometimes.  Thanks for your answer